# How can I find out which test method in a batch of test methods fails to run?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In the Test Explorer window of Visual Studio 2015 for C#, I select all the 360 test methods in my solution, and choose "Run Selected Tests". But not all of them are  executed, as indicated by the Output window:

> ------ Run test started ------
>
> The active Test Run was aborted because the execution process exited unexpectedly. To investigate further,
> enable local crash dumps either at the machine level or for process
> te.processhost.managed.exe. Go to more details:
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=232477
>
> ========== Run test finished: 188 run (0:00:12.7254721) ==========

How can I find out which test method fails to run, narrow the culprit test method down? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most subtle way to do it, but you could comment your tests one by one, and see at which point your run stops failing.

Comment: I would give the same advice but don't go one by one. Do half the tests, then do half of group that had the failing test, keep repeating till you have 1 test. This is a Binary Search and will in the worst case take 9 splits to find the failing test in the 360.