# Which unit test is currently running?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, crash, visual-studio-2017

This question is related to the problem where my unit test procedure is crashing but I don't know on which unit test.

I realise this question is a duplicate of [How can I find out which test method in a batch of test methods fails to run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446021/how-can-i-find-out-which-test-method-in-a-batch-of-test-methods-fails-to-run) but I need to try anyway:

I'm running some unit tests (about 118 of them), but one of them seems to make the Visual Studio unit test environment crash. This is what I see in the "output" window's "Tests" tab:

```
[5/02/2018 11:13:18 Informational] ------ Run test started ------
[5/02/2018 11:13:38 Error] The active Test Run was aborted because the execution process exited unexpectedly. The test execution process crashed while running the tests. To investigate further, open file:///C:/Users/DominiqueDS/AppData/Local/CrashDumps/vstest.executionengine.x86.exe.19136.dmp file in Visual Studio and choose "Debug in mixed mode".
[5/02/2018 11:13:38 Informational] ========== Run test finished: 65 run (0:00:19,6926824) ==========
```

The reason that I have that dump file is thanks to my Windows configuration which automatically creates such dumpfiles in case of a crashing application. (The procedure for this configuration is found under [this URL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181(v=vs.85).aspx))

Examining the dump file gives me more information on the test, which is failing: I have a hunch where I can find it, and in another thread, I find a function, calling a `method` which seems to contain the name of the unit test I'm running.

Although I know which test is failing, it's based on hunches and on dumpfiles I should even not generate, so I'm looking for another solution:

In the function `TEST_METHOD` in the file "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\VS\UnitTest\include\CppUnitTest.h", I've tried to add the following lines:

```
cout << "Test : ";\
cout << methodName;\
cout << "\n";\
```

I was hoping that this would show every test I wanted to run, but instead I get the error message that this is wrong (also using `std::cout` and `OutputDebugString()` function seems not to be allowed).

Hence my question: does anybody know a way to find out, in case one of my unit tests makes my test environment crash, how can I find out which test this is, without needing to generate and debug the Visual Studio dumpfile?

For your information: looking in the "Test Explorer" is not helping: I have a list of disabled tests, a list of successful ones, and a list of some which are not finished, and my failing test is not the first of the "not finished" ones.

Comment: I guess you run the tests in debug mode and step through it?

Comment: @UKMonkey: No, I run the tests in "Release" mode: seen the large amounts of tests I can't run them one by one, and running them in "Debug" mode is slowing down the process too much. In top of that the crash does not always occur.

Comment: "Although I know which test is failing"  sorry, why can't you debug it?

Comment: I'm working with a set of applications, and one of them (the defence) is verifying if any of the applications fail or crashes. The Windows wide configuration I've used interferes with this defense. Therefore I'd like to find a way to recognise the cause of the crash without it. For your information: I'm not asking this question as a result of a current need (I can debug the application and see what's going on), but if I need to re-configure my PC every time such problem occurs, I'll be losing a lot of time, so I'd like to find a future-safe method for detecting which test is currently running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: I've added the following line in the definition of `TEST_METHOD()`:

```
Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::Logger::WriteMessage(L#methodName);\
```